# htaccess rewrite rule - if the parameter value has forward slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We're building an API and I'm working on the rewriterule of my htaccess to make our URL like this `example.com/student/user/parameter1/parameter2`.

Everything is working fine until I caught a problem:

The `parameter2` consists of random alphanumeric and special characters, and it also includes a forward slashes (`/`). So whenever we're running the endpoint and captures the parameters, the values are wrong because it's reading the slashes within the parameter

Example: `example.com/student/user/anna/a!p=/dfa`

- Expected result should be `parameter1` is *`anna`* and `parameter2` is *`a!p=/dfa`*
- What's happening is `parameter1` is *`a!p=`* and `parameter2` is *`dfa`*

I'm hoping somebody would give me an idea on how to fix this.

This is our current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^student/user/(.*)/(.*)$ api/studentuser.php?name=$1&token=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Change first `(.*)` to be `([^/]+)`? Then it will never match the slashes and the latter will eagerly take all the rest

Comment: Hey, that one works. It's easier than I thought. Thank you very much @SamiKuhmonen

My htaccess looks like this now

Comment: My htaccess looks like this now

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^student/user/([^/]+)/(.*)$ api/studentuser.php?name=$1&token=$2 [L,B]